# Popup showing user threads in PHP, JS and HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I want to create the following:

I have a forum in **HTML** and **PHP**, and the different threads contains the `$user`, `$title`, `$id`...

How can a Pop-up with the user's differents posts can appear when I pass the mouse over the User pic in the forum?

I know that I have to do a **SQL SELECT** from the database, but how I know that the `username=$user` in the sentence will be the user which I have the mouse over?

Thanks!

Comment: sorry, this is far to broad to be answered. We have no code, no information about control flow, database structure, and much more.

Comment: short (very vage) answer: `SELECT * from posts where userId=$userId`

Answer (score 0):

You should save current username in javascript and another username in html tag of image like this:

```
<img id="img_<username>" data-username="<username>".... />
```

When user hovers over avater picture, you can use javascript to get data-username attribute and compare with current username. If they are equal then use ajax to request the user's differents posts from the database.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use AJAX in case you want the collection of posts to be fetched as and when you hover over the user image.
You can get the id(database record id) of the user on hover(I am expecting that you have id as the primary key in your user table):

```
$('.<class of your user div>').mouseover(function() {
   var id = this.id;
});
```

Now use AJAX to fetch MySQL data related to the user id.